# Editing a media query in google chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to edit a media query in google chrome's developer tools.  It's for [this page](https://superfly-css.github.io/superfly-css-component-button/src/test/html/).  I click `ctrl-shift-I` to open up the developer tools and then click the responsive icon.  I then select show media queries from the triple dot menu in the upper right hand corner and then right click on the `768px` media query which opens it such that I can edit it.

However when I try to put the media query on a new line such that I can see it better, the text gets mangled.  Just wanted to see whether anyone else is experiencing the same thing, before I file a bug report.

Comment: Yes, pressing Enter after `{` destroys the double-rectangle of the logo symbol and shows `â§‰` instead. You can reproduce it also by editing any part of the CSS without even invoking the responsive UI inspector. Also happens in the latest Chrome canary 59 and the old Chrome 51 so the bug was always there.

Comment: Report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=707662#